# Qual o equivalente ao if($_POST) no .Net (ASP.Net MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Estou codificando uma página no Visual Studio, em ASP.Net MVC e preciso exibir uma `div` apenas quando houver um `POST` nesta página.

Trata-se de um formulário que fará o `POST` na própria página. Quando houver o `POST`, exibirei uma mensagem de confirmação de envio.

O que tenho está mais ou menos assim:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend class="hidden">Contato</legend>

        <div class="msg-success">
            <p>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.</p>
        </div>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, "Nome*")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { id = "Name" })

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, "E-mail*")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { id = "Email" })


        <input type="submit" id="Send" name="Send" value="Enviar" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Gostaria de uma equivalência ao `if($_POST)` para exibir a `div`:

```html
<div class="msg-success">
    <h3>Obrigado!</h3>
    <p>Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.</p>
    <p>Aguarde, que logo entraremos em contato.</p>
    <span class="close">X</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Em ASP.Net MVC, existe as marcações nas *action* que indicam se elas irão receber requisições do Tipo `GET` ou `POST`. Como por exemplo isso:

```
[HttpPost] // Pode-se utilizar também [HttpGet], para receber requisições do tipo GET
public ActionResult ActionTest(object user)
{
    // esse action receberá apenas requisições do tipo POST
    return View();
}
```

Ou ainda há uma solução que é mais a maneira que você parece procurar (Modo `PHP`), que é assim:

```
public ActionResult ActionTest(object user)
{
    if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
    {
        //faça algo se for POST
    }
    return View();
}
```

Onde você pode verificar o tipo da requisição, isso não é melhor forma, a 1° é mais indicada, mas nada impede de você utiliza-la.

> Na segunda forma você pode validar qualquer tipo de requisição, por exemplo: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc.
>
> Obs: Citei que a 1° forma demostrada é melhor pelo fato de ser mais utilizada, mais simples de entender ao observar o código, e está presente na maioria dos materiais disponíveis sobre Asp.net MVC, mas as 2 maneiras podem ser utilizadas, escolhendo a que se adeque melhor as suas necessidades.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @Fernando, há alguns outros equivalentes, mas que não necessariamente previnem um formulário de ser submetido via `GET`:

## 1. [`Request.Form`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.form(v=vs.110).aspx)

`Request.Form` envelopa todo e qualquer valor vindo da requisição, não importando se é `POST` ou `GET`. É a base do *Model Binder*.

## 2. [`Request.InputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx)

Contém a requisição HTTP inteira. Pode ser lida da seguinte forma:

```
var dadosHttp = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Em tempo, ainda há o *Attribute* [`AcceptVerbs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) que pode definir para o filtro de *Action* se a *Action* aceita `POST`, `GET`, ambos, ou ainda outros, como `PUT`, `DELETE`, `HEAD`, `PATCH`, etc.:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] // Apenas POST
public ActionResult ActionPost(object user)
{
    // esse action receberá apenas requisições do tipo POST
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)] // Apenas GET
public ActionResult ActionGet(object user)
{
    // esse action receberá apenas requisições do tipo GET
    return View();
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)] // Ambos
public ActionResult ActionAmbos(object user)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Complementando o complemento, o [Request.InputStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx), é útil por exemplo, quando você quer tratar a requisição de forma manual, como por exemplo, recebimento de upload de arquivo, onde você recebe e lê todos os bytes da Request. E o [AcceptVerbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.acceptverbsattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), é forma bem flexível de restringir e aceitar vários argumentos em um mesmo método.